# Android - configuration file

Tags: java, android, security

I have one question about Android. I need to run one of my activities only once - at the beggining. So, usually the best solution is to create file which contains flag isFirstRun and check the value after application's start.

But in my application it is very important to protect this file before deleting by user. Even if user has rooted phone he should not be able to change the value or delete this file.

So, is it possible to write this information to any Android system registry or somewhere else where user can't change this value?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, it is not possible, for a simple reason, a root user have access to everything by definition. It won't make sense to have a program that has more rights than root.

Comment: Thanks. Your answer confirm my thoughts.

Comment: Please, click the Tick next to the question to close it and grant me points :)

Answer (score 2):

The user can delete all the data your application saves. Consider saving this information on some server.